# Add Event Listener to checkboxes when selected all at once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add event listener to all checkboxes, which are selected with span element "select all" --> see example bellow..

This code (i found it on other question on stackoverflow) works only if a checkbox is manually selected:

```
// Attach a change event handler to the checkboxes.
checkboxes.change(function() {
  enabledSettings = checkboxes
    .filter(":checked") // Filter out unchecked boxes.
    .map(function() { // Extract values using jQuery map.
      return this.value;
    }) 
    .get() // Get array.
    
  console.log(enabledSettings);
});
```

..but not when i click on the "select all"

Example on JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/f3n9vxzk/3/

Furthermore i would like to display selected checkboxes values on the right side of a page, for example:

If i choose TABLE2 under HR->New objects->Table, i would like to have (on the right side of a page) something similar to that on the left side, but only those values, which are checked..

..something like this:

[image]

So my question: is it possible to get parent value of each element in a tree, based on my structure? If yes, i would be very gratefull for any help or just hint (if i'm doing something wrong..).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code working with both manually select and click on the "select all"**

```js
let checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']");
let enabledSettings = [];

// function to show selected checkboxes
function checkbox_fun() {
  enabledSettings = checkboxes
    .filter(":checked") // Filter out unchecked boxes.
    .map(function() { // Extract values using jQuery map.
      return this.value;
    }) 
    .get() // Get array.
    
  console.log(enabledSettings);
}

$('.resultObjectsNew').on('click', 'span.selectAllNewObj', function(){
        var checked = $(this).parent().next().find('input').prop('checked');
        $(this).parent().next().find('input').prop('checked', !checked);
        checkbox_fun(); // function call
    });
    

// Attach a change event handler to the checkboxes.

checkboxes.change(function() {
  checkbox_fun(); // function call
});
```

Copy above code to below JSFiddle and successfully run code:

https://jsfiddle.net/f3n9vxzk/3/

Comment: heey, thank you very much, this works! :) nice trick to create a new function.. Maybe could you help me with second "question": to get each parent div text?

Comment: I can give you a hint so that you should try it by yourself for better understanding.
On selection of boxes you have the object and you can find their parents as well. So after finding required elements just show them in the right side of the page.